# Quantum attack on CTR

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, provable-security, modes-of-operation, quantum-cryptanalysis

I'm reading the [article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/236) named "Characterizing the qIND-qCPA (in)security of the CBC, CFB, OFB and CTR modes of operation".

An attack on CTR mode is presented in the article. The proof of thm 1 states:

- Adversary prepares the state $|+\rangle$ and makes a query to embedding oracle using it.
- Adversary receives $\sum_{x}|x\rangle|x\oplus s\rangle$ (in $b = 0$ case). Slightly different sum the adversary receives in $b=1$ case.

Here is the question: why we have sum over all $x$ here? An embedding oracle receives $|x\rangle$ and sends back $|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$. I.e. the first register remains unchanged.

Why we have sum over $x$ (with eqaul coefficients) in the oracle's answer then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why we have sum over all $x$ here?

The difference here is notational.  We use the + operator not to mean 'addition with some group operation', but instead that the state can be represented by a combination of orthogonal base states.

For example, if we have a state where we have two base vectors `|0>` and `|1>`, and they are of equal amplitude, we can represent the state as `|0> + |1>`.

Now, if we have $n$ such orthogonal base vectors, we can use the $\sum$ notation to mean `|0> + |1> + ... + |n-1>` in the obvious manner.

Now, when they write `|+>` (not to be confused with the + notation above), what they mean can be represented as $\sum_x$ |x>, however that misses a fine point.  `|+>` can be generated (and this is what the proof means by preparing) by taking the `|0>` state and applying the Hadamard (H) operator; in the 'computational basis' (which is the basis used in the representation $\sum_x$ |x>) every bit pattern has an equal amplitude.  However, there exists an alternative basis where the only nonzero amplitude is on a specific basis vector (denoted as +).  The reason this is important is if take this state, and apply the Hadamard operator to it again, it'll move it back to the `|0>` state; this does not apply to an arbitrary state, even if that state has equal amplitude with respect to all computational basis vectors (that is, performing a measurement on that state will generate all possible values with equal probability).

> I.e. the first register remains unchanged.

Welcome to Oz (that is, Quantum Mechanics), where this is not true (!).  In classical computation, reading a value has no effect on that value.  However, in Quantum Computation, it does.  This is not a trivial point; if you don't understand it, their proof will not make any sense.

The effect of taking `|x>|0>` and converting that into `|x>|f(x)>` is that the components become entangled, and in particular, if the `|x>` side was initially a pure `|+>` state, it no longer is.

What they do is they the `|x>|f(x)>` state (which they get from their encryption oracle) and change that into `|x>|f(x) ⊕ x>`.  This again affects the left side; if f(x) was $x \oplus s$ (for some secret constant $s$), then the state is `|x>|s>`; that is, the two sides are no longer entangled, and so the left side goes back to a pure `|+>` state.  If f(x) is something else, the two sides are sides are still entangled, and so the left side is something other than a pure `|+>` state.

They then use a Hadamard operator (and a measurement) to test the left hand side to see if it was a pure `|+>` state.

Yes, Quantum Mechanics is weird.  It is not irrational; it is just highly counterintuitive to anyone who hasn't worked with it a lot...

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of the article.

---

poncho's answer is great, but I'd like to just add some additional details that may help you in understanding the article.

When describing the action of a quantum oracle, it is enough to give its action on the basis states. Think of it as the equivalent classical result that knowing the action of a matrix on each vector of some basis completely characterizes it.

However, you have to recall that the oracle is applied to a superposition of states. Mathematically, this simply means that if you have a quantum state:
$$|\psi\rangle=\sum_i\alpha_i|i\rangle$$
And you want to apply some oracle $\mathcal{O}$ on it. Since $\mathcal{O}$ is in fact a matrix you will just have, by linearity:
$$\mathcal{O}|\psi\rangle=\sum_i\alpha_i\mathcal{O}|i\rangle$$
And now, if you know the expression of $\mathcal{O}|i\rangle$, you can just replace it.

In this case, we first start from the $|+\rangle$ state (which is an abuse of notation, it should be $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$ really), which is, omitting normalization:
$$\sum_x|x\rangle$$
We then only have to use the definition of the embedding oracle:
$$\mathcal{O}|x\rangle=|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$$
Thus, we use the linearity to obtain the expression of our state after having applied the oracle:
$$\sum_x|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$$
And this is why there is a sum over the $x$s: it comes from the fact that $|+\rangle$ is a superposition on the basis states, and from the fact that applying an oracle is done using linearity.

In the case of the CTR mode, we have $f(x)=x\oplus s$ since this is a stream cipher, and this gives you the expression in the article.

---

As a side note, it's also an abuse of notation to write:
$$\mathcal{O}|x\rangle=|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$$
Because the vectors don't have the same size here. What happens when using an embedded oracle is that a $|0\rangle$ state will be appended to the state prior to querying the oracle.